# Can't load webfonts-loader with webpack encore

Tags: svg, webpack, webpack-encore, webfont-loader

I'm setting up webfont-loader with webpack encore but nothing happens. No fonts or css are generated.

I don't know if I'm missing something on my configuration file.

```
//webpack.config.js

.addLoader({
    test: /\.font\.js/,
    use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader',
        {
            loader: 'webfonts-loader',
            options: {
                files: [
                    './app/Resources/assets/svg/*.svg'
                ],
                fontName: 'myfonticons',
                classPrefix: 'myfonticon-',
                baseSelector: '.myfonticon',
                types: ['eot', 'woff', 'woff2', 'ttf', 'svg'],
                fileName: 'app.[fontname].[hash].[ext]'
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

No errors are shown after running webpack.